# Installing Groovy 1.8 on Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I have *Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1*, which is based on *Eclipse 4.4.*

I installed the version of *Grails* I need, but I noticed that the *Groovy* compiler is at 2.3, whereas I need it to be at 1.8.

I've gone to `dist.springsource.org` on the *Eclipse Marketplace* to look for the Compiler 1.8. I can install it, but it automatically uninstalls the existing *Grails IDE*. On top of that, it doesn't appear under `Preferences - Groovy - Compiler` and I don't seem to be able to select it.

*What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use an earlier version of the Spring Tool Suite to access this particular compiler?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the snapshot update site to get the latest groovy-eclipse: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/

That includes the 1.8 compiler and the latest groovy-eclipse 2.9.1 builds that work with it - the 2.9.0 release had trouble with groovy 1.8. (But 1.8 is getting quite old now so we may drop support in the not too distant future).

That snapshot build should also be compatible with grails-ide, not sure why it would be uninstalling grails-ide (but remember that grails-ide is different to the grails-runtime - have you definitely installed both from the dashboard extensions page or just the runtime?)

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. Originally, I downloaded the STS, downloaded the Grails IDE and run time, changed Grails to a lower version I manually downloaded, then downloaded Groovy. By downloading Groovy *before* downgrading the Grails version, everything seems to run fine. Quite peculiar, but there you go - thanks for your help.